# How to turn on Live Web Preview in Web Essentials 2012 in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: css, visual-studio, web-essentials

I am trying to turn on the Live Web Preview feature of Web Essentials 2012 for when editing CSS files in Visual Studio. Everywhere I find the following instructions how to do that with none of them working for me:

1) Hit Ctrl + Alt + Enter -> nothing happens;

2) Right-click your web project item in Solution Explorer and click "Live Web Preview" to show the window and load the website. -> no such button exists.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Missin option for live preview.]

Comment: Guys, when you close a question, at least please comment on what is not clear.

Comment: I think you may be confusing Web Essentials with Web Essentials 2012

Comment: As far as I know, the former is for VS2010 and the latter - for VS2012?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think there is a feature called "Live Web Preview" in WE 2012 - the only documentation I can find describing such a feature relates to the original WE (for VS2010)

Comment: This is a legitimate question, should not have been closed.

Comment: The alternative for this in VS 2012 is the page inspector: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/visual-studio/visual-studio-2012-page-inspector

Comment: The Live Web Preview is now in the Page Inspector. See Mads Kristensen's comment here: http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/3740980-live-web-preview-allow-default-browser-instead-o

Comment: Agreed with all the other comments, this question should not have been closed.  Just because this relates to an older version of VS, does not mean you should close it.  The question is very clear: "How to turn on Live Web Preview in Web Essentials 2012 in Visual Studio 2012?"

Comment: one of the "unclearest" questions i've ever read...